# how to access last two dates sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I have date column in table

```
ColumnName: event_timestamp
2015-06-01 15:23:31.000
2015-06-01 15:25:21.000
2015-06-03 09:00:41.000
2015-06-03 09:14:49.000
2015-06-03 09:15:03.000
2015-06-03 09:15:23.000
2015-06-06 08:40:06.000
2015-06-06 08:40:19.000
2015-06-06 11:13:35.000
2015-06-06 11:13:53.000
2015-06-06 11:15:04.000
2015-06-06 11:15:30.000
2015-06-09 15:08:13.000
2015-06-09 15:08:33.000
2015-06-09 15:08:45.000
2015-06-09 15:09:05.000
```

Expected Output

```
2015-06-06
2015-06-09
```

I tried But failed

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,MAX(myDate),103),      
               (MAX(CONVERT(datetime,mydate,103)))-1 as DT 
FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,events.event_timestamp, 103)) myDate
       FROM events 
       Where event_timestamp Between '01-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM' 
                     AND '11-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM'
     ) tbl
```

Comment: unclear what you asking? What your second expected output means?

Comment: there is maximum date is 2015-06-09 and i also want exact previous date i,e 2015-06-06 from given column data.

Comment: why you put..."I want only"...then four dates......then "AND also same column...two more dates.."  which one is your expected....  Clarify and edit your question

Comment: which DB, mysql, Sql Server?

Comment: sql server 2008, ok i want only  2015-06-09,  2015-06-06

Answer (score 3):

Use Group By and Order By Clause with Desc then take Top 2 records

```
Select TOP 2 CONVERT(date, datecol) 
From #t
Group By CONVERT(date, datecol)
Order By CONVERT(date, datecol) Desc
```

<kbd>[See Working Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14536/3)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
-- grabs top 2 descending by date
select top 2 distinctDates
from (
    -- gets the distinct dates between your date range
    select distinct convert(date, mydate) as distinctDates
    FROM events e
    where e.timestamp Between '01-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM' AND '11-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM'
) dt
order by distinctDates desc
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to do a "GROUP BY" and a "LIMIT 2".  You will want to group by date (remember to disregard time) and then limit your results to 2.  Here is a link to both of these.

LIMIT : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp
GROUP BY : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html